# Set UserSetting "canLOCKEnvelopes"

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to update the usersetting for my API user to not be able to lock the envelope. I'm using the Update user settings API but it doesn't like the first line in my request: please look at this request and tell me at least what the first tag should be:

```
"<UpdateMemberSettings xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">"
```

Comment: <UpdateMemberSettings xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using XML formatted requests bodies, here's what a sample request for this call would look like:

```
<userSettingsInformation xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <senderEmailNotifications>
      <changedSigner>sample string 2</changedSigner>
      <deliveryFailed>sample string 6</deliveryFailed>
      <envelopeComplete>sample string 1</envelopeComplete>
      <offlineSigningFailed>sample string 7</offlineSigningFailed>
      <recipientViewed>sample string 5</recipientViewed>
      <senderEnvelopeDeclined>sample string 3</senderEnvelopeDeclined>
      <withdrawnConsent>sample string 4</withdrawnConsent>
   </senderEmailNotifications>
   <signerEmailNotifications>
      <agentNotification>sample string 12</agentNotification>
      <carbonCopyNotification>sample string 3</carbonCopyNotification>
      <certifiedDeliveryNotification>sample string 4</certifiedDeliveryNotification>
      <documentMarkupActivation>sample string 11</documentMarkupActivation>
      <envelopeActivation>sample string 1</envelopeActivation>
      <envelopeComplete>sample string 2</envelopeComplete>
      <envelopeCorrected>sample string 7</envelopeCorrected>
      <envelopeDeclined>sample string 5</envelopeDeclined>
      <envelopeVoided>sample string 6</envelopeVoided>
      <faxReceived>sample string 10</faxReceived>
      <offlineSigningFailed>sample string 13</offlineSigningFailed>
      <purgeDocuments>sample string 9</purgeDocuments>
      <reassignedSigner>sample string 8</reassignedSigner>
   </signerEmailNotifications>
   <userSettings>
      <nameValue>
         <name>sample string 1</name>
         <value>sample string 2</value>
      </nameValue>
   </userSettings>
</userSettingsInformation>
```

Note, you can use the REST API Operations link to see all potential request bodies for all the calls in the API:

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help

Comment: very nice Ergin ! this worked to straighten out the request object.... unfortunately it appears I don't have permission to update the property.

Comment: <errorCode>USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS</errorCode>
<message>This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource.</message>

Comment: so is this something I need to get someone to upgrade my permissions and if so who would I contact for that ?

Comment: If you don't have an account manager yet you can reach out to the automated emails you received after creating your dev account...